# Passing a pointer to function as a parameter to other function with multiple arguments

Tags: c, function, pointers, syntax

I would like to know how i can pass a pointer to a function to another function as a parameter, only the function that i wish to pass has multiple parameters. For example, my main function:

```
void main_func(float **D, float **w , int n, Pointer_to_func)
```

The function that i want to pass:

```
float func(int x_1, int y_1, int x_2, int y_2 ,int q)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: use `typedef`s to stop the syntax getting too hairy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or without a typedef (just for completeness, you generally do want the typedef):

```
void main_func(float **D, float **w , int n, float (*callback)(int, int, int, int, int));
```

Comment: woops..Your answers were alike..so i tagged it by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef float (*func_t)(int x_1, int y_1, int x_2, int y_2 ,int q);
void main_func(float **D, float **w , int n, func_t callback)
```

Comment: Thanks. Learned something. :)